# Permuting Small Sized Set in Practice

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

Imagine we have a set $S$ of $m$ elements and we wants to permutes the set elements. Thus the original position of each element should be unknown after permuting. If we define a permutation function as $\pi: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$, then the set elements are permuted securely if $n\le|S|$ where $n$ is the security parameter. So to permute $S$ we do $\pi (i)=r_i$, where $i$ is the original index of an element in the set, and $r_i$ is its new index.

However, if the set size is small ($|S|< n$) it seems the only way to securely permute it is to pad it first and then permute it, that increases storage cost.

Question: Is there any better and more cost effective way of permuting a set than the above scheme?

Comment: I believe you need to rethink what security means in this context.  It doesn't mean that the attacker can't take a guess at the permutation (and have a $1/|S|!$ chance of getting it correct).  Instead, it's that the attacker doesn't get any additional information about the permutation.  That is, even if $|S|=2$, the attacker knows that either the two elements remain where they are, or that they are swapped; but he doesn't know which it is.

Comment: @poncho Thank you for the answer. If we use a block cipher, as a permutation function, then given an input $i$ it outputs $r_i$ that is in the block ciphers range. Since the range of block cipher is usually large (e.g. 64-bit) $r_i$ can be any element in this range. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @poncho My question is: How do we permute a small sized set in practice?

Comment: What's wrong with the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is the archetypal way to randomly make a permutation of a set small enough that we can store the index of each element? Or/and (especially, for wider sets) enciphering the index using one of the many techniques of [Format-Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) and a fixed key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can generate uniform random numbers, you can use a variant of [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

```
//given an array s with the elements to be permuted
for i from n-1 to 1:
    t = rand(0, i) # inclusive
    swap(s[i], s[t])
```

Comment: Can I ask you what the "secret key" is in this scheme?

Comment: @user13676 The state of the random number generator. If you need it to be "keyed" so you can reproduce the permutation, then seed the random number generator.

Comment: In this pseudocode, `t = rand(0, i)` must generate a random integer uniformly distributed among the `i+1` integers in range `[0,i]` _inclusive_; otherwise the permutation is distinguishable from random, especially for small sets.

Comment: @fgrieu What can I use to get such property?

Comment: @user13676 There are a lot of posts on this kind of stuff online. Most programming languages have methods to help with this.

Comment: @mikeazo Thanks, this bit is more about programming than a cryptographic primitive.